# Change a predefined value on server before a functional test

Tags: javascript, integration-testing

I'm looking to change `requestHandler.value` to `5` for my functional styled tests.

When running the suite, creating `1000` documents in the db is not really an option, so is it possible to change it's value programmatically before running the suite and then reset it afterwards? I can create `5` documents in db before the test to work with.

Of coarse I can stub `countDocumentsInDb()` in unit tests to return what I need, but I've simplified logic below for the sake of the question.

`app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var requestHandler = require('./lib/requestHandler.js');
var PORT = 4000;

app.route('/validate')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    requestHandler.process(req, res);
  });

if (!module.parent) {
  server.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return;
    }
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

`requestHandler.js`:

```
var requestHandler = {

  value: 1000,

  process: function(req, res) {

    numberOfDocumentsInDb = countDocumentsInDb();

    if (numberOfDocumentsInDb === this.value) {
      res.send(true);
    } else {
      res.send(false);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = requestHandler;
```

`FVT` style test ..

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var request = require('supertest');
var chai = require('chai');
chai.should();
var server = require('../../app.js');

describe('app.js', function() {
  describe('/validate', function() {

    it('should return true if number of documents in db matches pre-defined value', function(done) {
      var fvtPromise = new Promise(function(fulfill) {
        request(server)
          .get('/validate')
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            res.body.should.equal(true);
            fulfill(null);
          });
      });
      fvtPromise.done(function() {
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your use case for hard coding value to 1000 on the server? The answer to that question would change the answer I would give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the **require.cache**, that will allow you to modify the values of requestHandler.
Is just an example I hope you get the idea.
- In the before each modify the require cache and set your **test values**
-In the after each set back the original values 
-Please notice that the `const server = require('./app.js');` is inside the test, so it will take the cache vales
e.g.

```
describe('test with cache', function(){
    require('./requestHandler');
    let originalValues;

    beforeEach(function() {
        originalValues = require.cache[ require.resolve('./requestHandler') ].exports;

        require.cache[ require.resolve('./requestHandler') ].exports = {
                    value:5,
                    process: function(req, res) {
                        //other stuff    
                    }
            };

    });

    afterEach(function() {        
        require.cache[ require.resolve('./requestHandler') ].exports = originalValues;        
    });

    it('should pass', function(){
        const server = require('./app.js');

        var fvtPromise = new Promise(function(fulfill) {
            request(server)
            .get('/validate')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                throw err;
                }
                res.body.should.equal(true);
                fulfill(null);
            });
        });
        fvtPromise.done(function() {
            done();
        });

        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });
});
```